# Access CakePHP webroot directory from Vue : Image Load

Tags: vue.js, cakephp

I have an app with Vue.js FrontEnd & CakePHP 3.8 BackEnd setup. I can upload images from within Vue frontend and would now like to access these assets from within my FrontEnd. My FrontEnd runs on another port than BackEnd, currently both locally.

There is no problem accessing static assets in my Frontend, also no problem in uploading dynamic assets to my Backend. I just find it hard to access them from my Frontend. My backend url is "http://wampprojects/holidays_backend/". Question is 'how can I set an img src attribute to load an asset from the backend?'.

Do I have to load it through API call or can I just set the src if I know the url & the path? Problem is I don't know the exact patH..

I have tried several things in code, but do not see how they can be relevant here.. I am trying to set an img url in Vue from CakePHP backend..

```
<img id="profilepic" src="@/assets/wmtrain_mobile-min.jpg" @click="showMenu">
```

I can access the path through my controller and view it in browser, but I cannot set the image src..

```
$wwwroot = Configure::read('App.wwwRoot');
$imageurl = Configure::read('App.imageBaseUrl');
$fullurl = $wwwroot.$imageurl;
```

I get an error "Not allowed to load local resource"..

With this url I can access an image through my browser. Why can't I access it from an img html element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use virtual property to your Image entity model.
Something like this :

```
protected $_virtual = ['fullpathimage'];

protected function _getFullpathimage() {
  $baseUrl = Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl');
  return $baseUrl.$this->get('imagepath');
}
```

the complete path of your image will be present in "imagepath" property